# Rails nested resources (many levels) Class treated as Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, nested-resources

These are my models:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :products  
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :company  
  has_many :prices  
end

class Price < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :product  
end
```

I defined them in routes as nested resources

```
resources :companies  
namespace :company do  
  scope ":company_id" do  
    resources :products do  
      resources :prices  
      resources :production_capabilities  
    end  
  end  
end
```

I wanted to put controllers and views in catalogs matching that structure

```
app/controllers/companies_controller.rb  
app/controllers/company/products_controller.rb  
app/controllers/company/product  
app/controllers/company/product/prices_controller.rb
```

As soon as i create product directory inside company and i try to call

```
Company.find(1).products
```

i get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'quoted_table_name' for Company::Product:Module
```

Does anybody know what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rails documentation explicitly recommends that we don't nest resources more than 1 level deep:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

You'll get URLs like this:

```
/company/1/product/4/price/5
```

That's not pretty. Try to avoid it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Guess i'll have to change my plans.